# Перебор элементов массива #1 в массиве #2, добавить не найденные элементы массива #2 в массив #3

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Здравствуйте! Не могу разобраться с перебором. Есть один массив вида:

```
var array1 = [
 {fruit_id: 435, fruit_name: 'Apple'},
 {fruit_id: 124, fruit_name: 'Lemone'},
 ...
];
```

И есть второй массив вида:

```
var array2 = [
 {category_id: 1, fruit_name: 'Apple'},
 {category_id: 2, fruit_name: 'Avocado'},
 {category_id: 3, fruit_name: 'Grapefruit'},
 {category_id: 4, fruit_name: 'Kiwi'},
 {category_id: 5, fruit_name: 'Lemone'},
 ...
];
```

Нужно сравнить 'fruit_name' массива #1 в массиве #2 на совпадения. И те элементы, которые не обнаружены в массиве #2, нужно закинуть в третий массив с данными из второго.
К этому же примеру должен получиться такой результат:

---

(В массиве #1 есть 'Apple' и 'Lemone', значит убираем их с массива #2, оставляя 
оставшиеся элементы массива #2)

```
var array3 = [
 {category_id: 2, fruit_name: 'Avocado'},
 {category_id: 3, fruit_name: 'Grapefruit'},
 {category_id: 4, fruit_name: 'Kiwi'}
];
```

Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array1 = [
 {fruit_id: 435, fruit_name: 'Apple'},
 {fruit_id: 124, fruit_name: 'Lemone'}
];

var array2 = [
 {category_id: 1, fruit_name: 'Apple'},
 {category_id: 2, fruit_name: 'Avocado'},
 {category_id: 3, fruit_name: 'Grapefruit'},
 {category_id: 4, fruit_name: 'Kiwi'},
 {category_id: 5, fruit_name: 'Lemone'}
];

array2.forEach(e => {
  if(!~array1.findIndex(elem => elem.fruit_name == e.fruit_name))
    // тут делаете что-то с тем елементом, которого нету в array1
    console.log(e);
});
```

[`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: Офигенно! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Объекты из массива #2 мы можем использовать как "e.object", а если мне нужно взять объект из массива #1, что тогда? "elem.object", не работает.

Answer (score 1):

> if(!~array1.findIndex(elem => elem.fruit_name == e.fruit_name))

Зачем так извращаться?

```
const array3 = array2.filter(item => !array1.includes(item))
```

Comment: вариант с фильтром хорош, но `findIndex` использовать всетаки прийдется

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych эээээм, зачем?

Comment: ну там самую малость обьекты...

Comment: Это вариант не подошел.